# Knockout reference binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a variable callsignLogin that is located in a **callsignConfig.js** file

```
define(['knockout'],function(ko){
    'use strict';

    var callsignLogin = ko.observable(false);
    return callsignLogin;
});
```

I have a **login.js** file that references in the dependencies the variable and if I am console.log-ing the variable it will be false.

```
define([callsignConfig],function(){
    console.log(callsignConfig); //it shows false
});
```

The problem I have is when I want to use it on the input to make it checked or not.

```
<input name="callsign" id="callsign" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: callsignConfig">
```

I also tried with callsignConfig() in the data-bind and it obviously doesn't work.

```
Error:Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: callsignConfig;
Bindings value: checked: callsignConfig
```

Comment: try returning callsignLogin from your login.js too...

Comment: I solved it. The html page was a child page and the variables from this html child page was referencing the parent variables.

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it as an answer so that others having similar problem in future can benefit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The html page was a child page with a child.js and the variables from this html child page was referencing the parent.js variables.